# SQL Server 2008 Maintenance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi all i'm completely new to maintenance tasks on SQL Server. I've set up a datawharehouse, that basically reads a load of xml files and imports this data into several tables using an SSIS. Now i've set indexes on the tables concerned and optimized my ssis. However i know that i should perform some maintenance tasks but i dont really know where to begin. We are talking about quite a bit of data, we are keeping data for up to 6 months and so far we have 3 months worth of data and the database is currently 147142.44 MB with roughly 57690230 rows in the main table. So it could easily double in size. Just wondering what your recommendations are?

Comment: Just to add the SSIS package runs every hour and imports data. Depending on usage, the data read in could be anywhere between 1,000 and 500,000 rows of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is the usual [index rebuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx) and [statistics update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) which are part of normal maintenance, I would look at all of the currently long running queries and try to do some index tuning, before the data size grows. Resizing the database also forms part of a normal maintenance plan, if you can predict the growth and allocate enough space between maintenance runs then you can avoid the performance hit of space auto allocation (which will always happen at the worst possible time)